# Нужно сделать так, чтобы python3 фильтровал вводные значения (текст или число)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пишу telegram бота на **python** и столкнулся с проблемой -- боту требуется ввести число, но если ввести текст, то код крашится, нужно чтобы python фильтровал вводимые данные

```
else:
    ID = int(message.text)    # перевод строки в числовое значение (в этом месте код крашится)
    white_list = ID in priority    # проверка на то, чтобы введённый  ID не совпадал с массивом других ID

    if white_list == False:    # если не совпало то записываем в переменную и уведомляем об этом 
        id_target = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ID записан")
```

Comment: скинь весь код, этого мало

Comment: что значит _"нужно чтобы python фильтровал вводимые данные"_? приведите пример входных данных и желаемый результат

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть в try/except

Comment: Какое содержимое message.text?

Comment: Требуется ввести id - например 1234567, но если юзер бота по ошибке напишет любой текст, то бот крашится

Answer (score 1):

```
if message.text.isdigit():
    ID = int(message.text)
else:
    bla_bla_bla
```